# OpenSSH on Ubuntu 16.04 shows ECDSA keys in an unusual format

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to SSH to my server, and the client is asking about the authenticity of the host.

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:bla bla bla
```

With every version of OpenSSH I've used, ECDSA (or RSA) keys were shown something like

```
a7:3h:75:5d:si:9v:3g...
```

On Ubuntu 16.04 they're being shown like

```
c2ymd4uGIG3y34R78BcrykBVT...
```

I have another way to access the server, and I'm trying to verify the fingerprint by running `ssh-keygen -lf ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`. But this outputs something like `2048 a7:3h:75:5d:si:9v:3g...`. Even ignoring the colons, they don't match. I can't be 100% positive this isn't because of a MITM attack, but it's highly unlikely.

How can I verify the key signatures? All the solutions I've found seem to deal with a different version of `ssh-keygen`, though I can't figure out what version I have, or what others have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5 user@host` to use old-school MD5 hashes, or store this in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
FingerprintHash md5
```

You server is probably using old openssh version which does not support new sha256 hashses.

Comment: Server is 14.04. From what I had read any server using MD5 for SSH key fingerprints must be quite old and not updated, so I thought that must not be it (I think I haven't been doing `dist-upgrade`). In the command `ssh -O FingerprintHash=md5 host`, by `host` do you mean `user@host`? Otherwise I'm missing something. And I just added  `FingerprintHash md5` to the config file, restarted SSH, and it worked fine.

Comment: If you connect to the host with `ssh user@host`, then yes.

Comment: For `ssh-copy-id` it's `-o` (lowercase). Perhaps OpenSSH uses the lowercase for this option, in its family of programs? I don't know of every OpenSSH command, but I'm guessing they're consistent.

Comment: Yes, it is lowercase for both `ssh` and `ssh-copy-id`. Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: I suspected, but didn't want to jump to conclusions. :)

Comment: that command doesn't work for me, I get `command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: fingerprinthash`

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer solves the problem of forcing newer clients to show MD5 hashes, it doesn't specifically solve the problem of forcing a server to show its fingerprint with a specific hash function when calculating fingerprints on the server. To clarify that a bit, when checking fingerprints, you need to match the one shown on the client to the true value on the server. @Jakuje's answer deals with getting the client to use a different hash function, this answer deals with getting the server to show you the hash using a different hash function. It doesn't matter whether you change the server or the client's hash function, just so they're the same.

To find a host's fingerprint, on that host execute:

```
# Works with the version of OpenSSH on 16.04 but not 14.04
# (on 14.04 I have OpenSSH_6.6.1p1; on 16.04 it's OpenSSH_7.2p2)
# Check your version with with `ssh -V`
cd /etc/ssh
ssh-keygen -l -E md5 -f ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
```

Of course, you can change `md5` to any supported hash function, and you may need to change `ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` depending on the key type you're using (e.g. `ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`).

Comment: this assumes you have access to the host, no?